# Design update functions and their naming convention

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, ngrx, naming-conventions, ngrx-component-store

I am writing updaters for my component-store.

The situation is as follows:

1. I have an Array Of models named processingStatuses.
2. Sometimes t I have to update all of them.
3. Sometimes I just want to update one of them.

I am wondering which design is better.

1. Separate this into 2 functions.

```
readonly updateOneProcessingStatus = this.updater(...);
readonly updateProcessingStatuses = this.updater(...);
```

2. Always pass the whole array to the updater.
   When I want to update one, I get the array from the old state, modify it and then pass it to the `updateProcessingStatuses()`.

```
readonly updateProcessingStatuses = this.updater(...);
```

And I also want to know if my naming is acceptable or not. (e.g. plural)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, it is better to create two functions `update()` and `updateRange()`. By doing this your API will be cleaner and when new developer will try to update, then she/he will have clear understanding what method  should be used.

In addition, it can be seen that this approach is used in Entity Framework. [UpdateRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.updaterange?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-updaterange(system-object())) and just simple [Update()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-6.0) method

Comment: thanks! If it's ok, I still have one question to ask. In my case, the target I want to update is billingResults which is an array of billingResult. Does updateBillingResultsAll() & updateBillingResults() make sense to you? or do you have any advice?

Comment: I would be consistent and would call like this `updateBillingRange()`

Comment: so `updateBillingRange()` and `updateBilling()` ?

Comment: @NickLin yeah, you are absolutely right! :)